# Vertically centred div with scrollbar if too large of parent in Safari

Tags: css, overflow

I have the following selection of divs:

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="middle">
    <div class="inner">
        <p>
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like it so that the .outer div is the height of the page, the .inner div is centred on the page vertically and that if its contents get too large for the page to contain it (including padding etc.) then a scroll bar appears **on the .inner div rather than the page**.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5ab9yv6/1/) with my efforts thus far. The example works well in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari. Can anyone explain why? Or point me in the direction of getting a cross browser solution?

Comment: This is working just as you want it to be. Please describe the problem better.

Comment: When I view the fiddle, the green doc (.inner) is not visible at all. Is it different for you? Which browser are you using?

Comment: Yes i can see it, plus it has a scrollbar (i am using chrome, but it also shows up on firefox).

Comment: I worked on this problem for a while.  The issue is that the table layout engine interprets the height as a minimum value, hence, the table height will be automatically adjusted to display as much content as possible, which means, the inner/green div cannot compute the height needed to get the scrolling to trigger as you want it.  I tried some tricks with an absolute positioned inner div, but then the top/bottom padding was not right.  I think you need some JavaScript/CSS to touch up the height values.  Would this work for you?

Comment: You are right @wazaaaap, it works fine in chrome. I was viewing it initially in safari. Any ideas why it doesn't work there? I will try and edit the question to reflect the actual nature of my problem.

Comment: Hi @MarcAudet, are you viewing in Safari too? Javascript would work for my current application but I would prefer to find a css solution that works across all browsers and it seems like there should be one?

Comment: Is this working in Safari: http://jsfiddle.net/c5ab9yv6/3/

Comment: Safari is having issues with oveflow and i don't think i know the answer. Sorry.